# Python Error: dialog not supported

Tags: python, dialog

I'm getting this error on running a python script (see screen shot). The rest of the menu are fine apart from the StaticIP menu that's causing the exception.

https://github.com/turnkeylinux/confconsole/blob/master/confconsole.py

Appreciate any leads.

[image: TK1]

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the stock python-dialog package won't work.
So the author advised to install the forked version of pythondialog.
Works like a charm now!

https://github.com/turnkeylinux/pythondialog

Answer (score 0):

The "dialog not supported" string/error message one can read on the screenshot is not part of (at least current) pythondialog from http://pythondialog.sourceforge.net/.

Did you report a bug at https://sourceforge.net/p/pythondialog/_list/tickets or ask your question on the [pythondialog mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/pythondialog/mailman/)? Which "author" suggested to use which "forked version"? This is rather unclear...